# CherryPy: using RoutesDispatcher plus an alternate dispatcher for cpstats

Tags: cherrypy

I'd like to use cpstats (http://www.cherrypy.org/browser/trunk/py3/cherrypy/lib/cpstats.py) in an application already entirely based on RoutesDispatcher. How can I either:

1. have RoutesDispatcher route to cpstats, or
2. use both RoutesDispatcher and the ordinary dispatcher in the same tree, with the latter running only cpstats?

Answer (score 1):

You can write in your config:

```
[/stats]
request.dispatch = cherrypy.dispatch.Dispatcher()
```

...to use the default dispatcher for that URI.